# Limit the number of products displayed for desktop and mobile devices on WooCommerce shop and archive pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

How do i set a different product per page for desktop/mobile?

At the moment i have this code in functions.php:

```php
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'new_loop_shop_per_page', 15 );

function new_loop_shop_per_page( $cols ) {

    $cols = 15;
    return $cols;
}
```

But on mobile i want to show 10 products insted of 15 products. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Class here: http://mobiledetect.net/

```
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';

 
function new_loop_shop_per_page( $cols ) {
    $device = new Mobile_Detect;
    $cols = $device->isMobile() ? 10 : 15;
    return $cols;
}
```

or write a detection function yourself using $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] filtering for known mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wp_is_mobile()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/) - Test if the current browser runs on a mobile device (smart phone, tablet, etc.)

So you get:

```php
function filter_loop_shop_per_page( $products ) {
    if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
        $products = 10;
    } else {
        $products = 15;
    }

    // OR shorthand
    $products = wp_is_mobile() ? 10 : 15;

    return $products;
}
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'filter_loop_shop_per_page', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score -1):

In the WP documentation there is a way to to check the current browser runs on a mobile device or not.

You can try `wp_is_mobile()`  (I didn't test it myself.)

[Reference Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/)

Comment: Same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/72098009/11987538 - 
Make sure when you post an answer it contains a different solution than other answers, otherwise it's pretty useless to repeat existing answers